# Query a map from DynamoDB in Amazon Athena

Tags: amazon-athena

I have a column in Dynamo DB which is backed up in S3, and is something like this:

```
{"attributes":
{"m":{"isBirthday":{"s":"0"},
"party":{"m":{"cake":{"bOOL":false},"pepsi":{"bOOL":false},"chips":{"bOOL":false},"fries":{"bOOL":false},"puffs":{"bOOL":false}}},"gift":{"s":"yes"}}},
"createdDate":{"n":"1521772435189"},
"modifiedDate":{"n":"1521772435189"}}
```

I need to use this S3 file in Athena and run query on the items in this "attributes".
I have tried multiple options to map it and then retrieve the values. However it doesnot work.

Please someone let me know how do I map it to my athena table to run query on this.

Comment: Can you please share your Athena table definition?  Did you get error messages?

Comment: I need to fetch the number of pepsi, from party map - "party":{"m":{"cake":{"bOOL":false},"pepsi":{"bOOL":false},"chips":{"bOOL":false},"fries":{"bOOL":false},"puffs":{"bOOL":false}}},"gift":{"s":"yes"}}} - I have mapped it to String in Athena. I need to know that should I map differently when creating table